# Converting Vaadin Table to Vaadin Grid

Tags: vaadin7

We use a lot of tables in our website ( Vaadin Table ), but our customer just told us that they want to be able to edit inside the  table.  Now, I know that is possible in Table ( I already got that to work ), but I sort of like the edit mechanism for Grid better.  Is there an easy way to convert Vaadin Table to Vaadin Grid?  Since Grid is not a drop in replacement, I know it will take some conversion work.  Just wondering how hard people have found it, and if there is any documentation out there on doing such a conversion.

Here is our normal table usage:

```
public final class ReplenishmentOrderMgmtView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private final Table table;
    private static final String[] DEFAULT_COLLAPSIBLE = {
    "contactFirstName",
    "contactLastName",
    "supplierName",
    "carrier", "carrierService", "trackingNumber"
    };
    private static final Object[] VISIBLE_COLUMNS = {
    "barcode",
    "contactUserId",
    "contactFirstName",
    "contactLastName",
    "PO",
    "orderId",
    "cellId",
    "cellName",
    "wmsItem",
    "description",
    "supplierId",
    "supplierName",
    "statusDesc",
    "resizedBinQty",
    "expectedOnDockDate",
    "shipQuantity",
    "receivedQty",
    "lastReceiptDate",
    "carrier",
    "carrierService",
    "trackingNumber",
    "creationDate"
    };
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
    "Barcode",
    "Contact User",
    "First Name",
    "Last Name",
    "PO Number",
    "Replenishment Order Id",
    "Cell Id",
    "Cell Name",
    "Part",
    "Description",
    "Supplier Id",
    "Supplier Name",
    "Status",
    "Resized Bin Qty",
    "Expected On Dock Date",
    "Ship Quantity",
    "Received Qty",
    "Last Receipt Date",
    "Carrier",
    "Carrier Service",
    "Tracking Number",
    "Creation Date"
    };


    private Table buildTable() {
        final Table table = new Table();
        table.setSizeFull();
        table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_BORDERLESS);
        table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES);
        table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_COMPACT);
        table.setSelectable(true);

        table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);

        table.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);

        updateList( table );

        table.setSortContainerPropertyId("creationDate");
        table.setSortAscending(true);

        table.setColumnHeaders( COLUMN_NAMES );

        // Allow dragging items to the reports menu
//        table.setDragMode(TableDragMode.MULTIROW);
        table.setMultiSelect(false);

        table.addActionHandler(new ReplenishmentOrdersActionHandler());

        table.addValueChangeListener(event -> this.selectItemFromTable());

        table.setImmediate(true);

        return table;
    }
}
```

There is also some binding involved in there - my data source is a java bean.  Obviously, I am only includine code that will impact the table itself.  Any advice or opinions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there an easy way to convert Vaadin Table to Vaadin Grid?*

**No.** You have to declare and apply properties of Grid and no direct way to have conversion between Grid and Table. Both are different elements and can not be switched with so called *minimal changes* in terms of UI.

Because switching involves lot of things to be considered like,

- Data source of table can works fine with Grid or not.
- Style applied to table will not work for Grid (*i.e.* Valo theme styles, responsive style)
- Events of table are not same as Grid. Table has value change event while Grid has item click listener.
- and so on...

However, you can have same container for both the elements. Container data source can be common between both the elements. Note that Grid has some limitations like it does not support component in row while table supports that. On the other hand Grid is fast, optimized with some extra features like freeze column, support component in header etc. Same way table is *descendant* of Grid and will not have some features which are supported by Grid.